# LDO requirement for battery powered micro-controllers

Tags: battery-operated, ldo, lora

What are the selection parameter for battery powered ultra low powered application?
(Battery capacity of 3700mAh, 3.7V 18650 Li-ion)

I'm designing an application with MSP430/Atmega328 + RF micro-controller (LoRa/Sigfox/BT-LE)

Here Atmega can run on voltage range above 3.3v but RF micro-controller needs voltage from 2.2 to 3.3 Volt, which makes it difficult if entire device is powered by 3.7 V Li-ion battery. Fully charged battery initially has 4.2 - 4.5 V.
Hence its needed to have a LDO before RF micro-controller (150 mA).

This also means LDO will always be in circuit and will dissipate power which will affect battery life. I want to achieve at least few month to years of battery life.

I want to understand the selection parameter that are important for choosing right LDO for this application.
Quiescent Current, Drop-Out voltage.

Any other thought on this application is also advisable.

(Please do suggest changes in question if looks inappropriate or incorrect question)

EDIT - removed less important part of question (using Boost) as I figured out from Li-XX batteries discharge graph, its not needed.

UPDATE - I am targeting for two types of applications:
1) RF Remote Control and

2) Sensor Node

UPDATE: I found this article which theoretically clears many aspects
https://www.analog.com/en/analog-dialogue/articles/applying-low-dropout-regulators.html

Comment: "when battery voltage drops below 1.8v" if you ever hope to recharge that cell, you need to cease discharge long before that.

Comment: 1.8v too much to ask. but in case if we need to maintain 3.3 even in case battery goes below 3.3v. But as i have seen a discharge curve of Li-ion battery (http://www.ibt-power.com/Battery_packs/Li_Ion/Li_Ion_DiscTGph.JPG), it looks ok. I guess if it goes below 2.2, then its time to replace or recharge battery.

Comment: You might be better off doing boost + LDO and running as much as you can from the boost converter then relying on the short duty cycle of the RF comms to keep the rating of the LDO as close to the load requirement as possible. Then you protect the cell by disabling the boost converter whilst leaving it connected... this might take a bit of thought as the most basic boost converter layout always has a path from input to output. This might mean a power gating FET before the boost converter is better.

Comment: Anything below about 2.8V is considered "flat" for a LiIon battery.  Attempting to use a boost converter to drain it below that voltage risks permanently damaging it.

Comment: If you are not well experienced with battery charger designs the best idea is to use a commercially available charger with Li battery types. Choose one that is designed specifically for the battery you plan to use.  As others are trying to tell you - uncontrolled discharging (and especially charging) can easily ruin you battery. In a worst case you might even over heat the battery and cause a fire.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Choosing a battery based on requirements and circuit's voltage](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/468527/choosing-a-battery-based-on-requirements-and-circuits-voltage)

Comment: As you can see im not much into charging stuff, that will make the project more complex. I just want to concentrate on power consumption and battery life. I have good idea about power consumption pattern of my microcontroller and RF chip. I dont want LDO for microcontroller, I just need it for RF chip as it has 3.3v max voltage requirement. And battery voltage starts from 4.2V. Thats is the reason im more interested in choosing LDO which consumes very less power when everything is in sleep and in active mode. I like the idea of (Anders Petersson) switching off regulator.

Comment: "I want to achieve at least month or years of battery life." - what capacity is your Li-ion battery?

Comment: Battery capacity of 3700mAh, 3.7V 18650 Li-ion. Target application is RF remote/ sensor node.

Comment: Not relevant to your main question but FWIW, an 18650 cell advertised at 3700 mAh capacity is likely to have an actual delivered capacity substantially lower than that. You'll probably achieve more like 3000 mAh at beginning of life.

Comment: That is very obvious @pericynthion. I did assume 15%  of derating for battery capacity.

Answer (score 1):

I just answered a similar question: [Choosing a battery based on requirements and circuit's voltage](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/468527/choosing-a-battery-based-on-requirements-and-circuits-voltage/468538#468538)

To achieve really long battery time, you need to shut down everything except some electronics with tiny current draw that wakes up the system based on your choice of event. This could control the regulator shutdown pin, making quiescent current of the regulator and other parts irrelevant.

If RF needs 2.2-3.3 and no other parts require 3.3V or higher, you're best off using a regulator of maybe 2.5 V output, as atmega can run from this voltage when using a low clock speed. Lower voltage means lower current consumption too for many ICs.

It might or might not be advantageous to use a switching regulator to avoid wasting the power of the excess voltage when going from ca 4 down to 2.5 V, for the times when the circuit is active. Look at efficiency and quiescent current for the switching regulator at the load current that you expect.

Kevin Darrah explains how he solved a similar application. You can look at his TrigBoard here https://www.kevindarrah.com/wiki/index.php?title=TrigBoard or on Youtube.

Low-power design is fun -- and time-consuming.

Comment: Oh its really great, https://youtu.be/w_tNCdPDMmA video is really well explained. Clears out many concepts. Thank for information @Anders Petersson. I was also thinking about regulator shut down pin, and thanks for pointing it out. Not using regulator is not an option as i've RF chip which needs 3.3 v and battery voltage is in range of 4.2 to 3 approx. So my idea is to use LDO only for RF chip and not for microcontroller. Microcontroller can run directly on battery. This way i can control LDO shutdown pin to turn it off through uC. What do you think?

Comment: Probably not a great idea to run MCU and RF on different voltages, as they need compatible signal levels when communicating (check datasheets!). Lowest power will be if you add some electronics that trigger the regulator without needing the MCU (as Kevin Darrah); then the regulator can shut down the MCU. My 2nd choice would be low-quiescent regulator and only depower the RF.

Comment: Kevin Darrah is using a lowpower timer to control LDO. I dont know how this will work in my case. I was trying to use this for remote control application in which case I can not turn off LDO as microcontroller need to be waiting for key interrupt. this low power timer might work in case of sensor node i guess. I will also look into this aspect.